# Can You Flank with Reach?

Tags: dnd-4e, weapons, combat-advantage

Can you flank an enemy you're not adjacent to if you have a reach weapon? How does it work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### No, You Can't

From the Rules Compendium (pg. 218):

> To flank an enemy, a creature and at least one of its allies must be adjacent to the enemy and on opposite sides or corners of the enemy's space.

It specifically says adjacent, so no. This means that you won't get any combat advantage from flanking for your attack, nor will any allies get it from your presence.

### There's a Feat

In the Player's Handbook 3, there is a feat called Polearm Flanker:

> **Benefit:** When you make a melee attack with a polearm against a target that is not adjacent to you, choose an unoccupied square that is adjacent to both you and the target. You are considered to occupy that square for the purpose of determining if you flank the target for the attack.

Of course, this only works if you specifically have a polearm. There are a number of superior weapons that are a polearm and also another weapon type. The greatspear, for example, is both a spear and a polearm.

Also, only you get the benefit. Your allies still don't get any benefit to their attacks unless you are actually adjacent.